# Why do some questions look in lighter color?

Tags: bug

What I mean appears in the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Why does the first question look lighter than the second? Any reason for this? (I haven't clicked on it yet)

I put the tag "bug" since I don't know the reason. Sorry if I'm wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Presumably you're ignoring one of the question's tags. For example, if I ignore the abstract algebra tag, I see a similar phenomenon:

[image]

If you look to the right of the question list, you can see a place to manage your ignored tags, as seen here:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it seems I was unintendedly ignoring the tag "elementary-number-theory". Thanks.

Comment: If this answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, I was immediately going to accept it, but the site didn't allow :) Now, I'm on-line again and accepted.